# Get all ordered combinations of list python

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to generate all n-item combinations of a list of numbers while maintaining numerical order. So for example, if the list were

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

The ordered combinations of length 3 would be:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]
```

To be clear, I have to maintain numerical order, so [1,4,2] would not be a desired outcome.

Is there a function that does this, or a fast algorithm that would get it done? The actual list is 111 and I will be choosing 100 items. Thanks.

Comment: You used the word combination, but you described permutation (permutations retain order). Can you clarify?

Comment: Permutation means that order matters, but it doesn't retain numerical order, so it will also produce [2,4,1] from the list above, which is not what I need.

Comment: [How to get all combinations of length n in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974126/how-to-get-all-combinations-of-length-n-in-python)

Comment: "The actual list is 111 and I will be choosing 100 items." Just to make sure, you understand that there are almost half a quadrillion such combinations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you just looking for all the combinations of a given list of length n? If so you can just use combinations from itertools. Either way you'll probably want to go with itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [1,2,3,4]
for item in combinations(numbers, 3):
    print sorted(item)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants permutation or combination? If it turns out OP wanted combinations, I'll remove my post.

Comment: @user590028 Yeah, I originally thought permutations but when I saw the expected output it pointed towards combinations. However I think what he wants is combinations while preserving the order that they appear in the list. For example you can have [1,3,4] but not [3,1,4].

Comment: Thimble is correct. I want combinations while preserving order, which is why neither the pure combination or permutation functions from itertools do what I need.

Comment: @TomR that depends on how you would define order. In your example you show [2,3,4] being before [1,2,4]. Normal conventions would have that being at the bottom. You would need to define what order you want. Combinations automatically ordered them starting with the first index and moving forward.

Comment: Thimble had the right answer (so I removed my permutations answer). All he needed todo was sort the result. I've edited his answer to reflect your needs

Comment: That works. I don't care at all about the order of the combinations, just that the combinations themselves are ordered. Thimble's answer is perfect.