# How to make for efficent nested loop with a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

the below python code works with a pandas dataframe but I was wondering how to make it more efficient.

```
columns = list(data)
lenn=len(columns)
lenn

i=0
while i<lenn:
    j=i+1
    while j <lenn:
        print(data.iloc[:,i]*data.iloc[:,j])
        #print(data.iloc[:,j])
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `shift`

```
data.shift(axis=1)*data
```

Update 1

```
s=data.shift(axis=1)*data
for x in list(s):
    print(s.loc[:,s])
```

Update 2

```
for x in list(data):
    print(data.loc[:,x],data.shift(axis=1).loc[:,x])
```

Update 3

```
import itertools
t=list(itertools.combinations(range(df.shape[1]), 2))
for x in t:
    print(data.iloc[:,x[0]],data.iloc[:,x[1]])
```

Comment: amazing! but what if I wanted to select each column?

Comment: @andrewcz change the shift to shift(1), check the update

Comment: does that select each column individually? what is i wanted to print out each column?

Comment: @andrewcz will update, also if the update work for you , would you like accept, check mark at the left

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much for your help!! what if just wanted to print out the columns not multiply them. just select every adjacent column?

Comment: If I wanted to print columns 1,2 and 1,3  and 1,4 and then 2,3  2,4 and 3,4....

Comment: Thats amazing!! yes!! Thank you!! although i dont really understand the code. Is there a simpler way possibly.

Comment: @andrewcz check what i did by using intertools in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429507/python-combinations-without-repetitions