# Which loop can be used for continuing while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, sequence

I want to know how to condense this code using loops. It is a repeated sequence of (i) variable definition (ii) while loop condition ...(iii) variable increment

```
list_main = []
x1 = 1
while x1<= n:
    x2 = x1
    while x2 <= n:
        x3 = x2
        while x3 <= n:
#continue the sequence: x(i) = x(i-1) ; while x(i) <= n:
 
            list_ = [x1,x2,...]
            list_main.append(list_)
            x3 = x3 + 1
        x2 = x2 + 1
    x1 = x1 + 1
```

I want something like this:

```
max_x = 10 #maximum number of 'x's
#code
list_ = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10]
```

**Edit**

If Number of 'x's is 2 and n is 5, then my desired output, i.e., list_main is

```
list_main = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[4,4],[4,5],[5,5]]
```

If the number of 'x's is 3 and n is 3, then my desired output is

```
list_main = [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,3],[3,3,3]]
```

Comment: What’s the ultimate point of this…?

Comment: `list_ = [n] * n`?

Comment: No, your aim is not to create a list of “x’s”. The individual x’s are an irrelevant intermediary. The ultimate goal is to create a… list of values…‽

Comment: @deceze yes, my ultimate aim is to create a list of values. I mentioned my desired output in an edit. Please check it.

Comment: I apologise for not having made myself clear the first time.

Comment: Something something [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)?

Comment: ```itertools.combinations()``` might work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46623112/18843462), your problem can be solved like this:

```
max_x = 10
n = 5
values = []
i = 1
while i <= n:
    list_values.append(i)
    i = i + 1
count = [max_x] * n
list_main = list(unique_combinations_from_value_counts(values,count,max_x))
```