# How to get all possible vectors of size n with elements [x,y]

Tags: python, list, combinations

My question is similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974126/how-to-get-all-combinations-of-length-n-in-python), but rather I want to find all possible vectors of a given size comprising `[x,y,...]` elements. For instance, given a list `[1,2]`, how do I find all possible vectors with elements `1` and `2`, with size 3? in this case it is:

```
(1,1,1)
(1,1,2)
(1,2,1)
(2,1,1)
(1,2,2)
(2,1,2)
(2,2,1)
(2,2,2)
```

What is an elegant way to do this? I'm imagining that subsequent `for` loops is not the best way to do this. In my real case I am actually looking for $2^{8}$ combinations since I am looking for vectors with 8 elements.

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations`

Comment: Use `itertools.product([1,2],repeat = 3)`

Comment: See "itertools.product"

Comment: Nice guys, thanks. I knew about `itertools.combinations`, but couldn't get it to work. `itertools.product` solves the problem!

Comment: @JohnColeman could you please add your answer, as it is better than mine.

Comment: @Sos This is almost certainly a duplicate. I just wasn't in the mood to track down a good dup target for it.

Comment: @JohnColeman sure, I understand. I did try searching for a similar question but wasn't lucky, but I also think it must've been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above, I got it working like so:

```
[x for x in itertools.product(*[x for x in ((1,2),)*3])]
#out:
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does the work (it works well with 8 elemements too):

```
l=sum([list(set(itertools.permutations(i))) for i in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([1,2], 3))], [])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
```