# How to print all the unique combinations of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, unique

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to print all the unique combinations from the list like this

```
[ [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3] ]
```

Note: Without using any module

Comment: This post may be useful -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907108/11433654

Answer (score 0):

You need a variant of the [powerset recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

list_a = [1, 2, 3]

out = list(map(list, powerset(list_a)))
```

output: `[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

If you don't want to use `itertools` you can quite easily reimplement `combinations` and `chain` using list comprehensions or functions.